# Add trailing slash to end of folder with matching folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i want to add trailing slashes to end of folders which does not have trailing slash

I use below code and it working fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Now how do i make above condition work only when path starts with blog

for example it should add slash  only to `https://example.com/blog` or `https://example.com/blog/folder1`

and ignore others like `https://example.com/docs` or `https://example.com/docs/blog`

Comment: Would like to ask one question here, if `/`slash is not there is it giving you error? OR do you have other rules also apart from these in your htaccess file?

Comment: no its not giving me error , its redirecting me correctly.

Comment: Ok then adding slashes is helping you in other things, just asking so that it's clear to me, thank you.

Comment: btw do u know the solution ?

Comment: No trying to understand first that why you are trying to add / to urls, even urls working for you.

Comment: its just /blog/ is professional compared to /blog